# Group json data with common fields on php

Tags: php, sql, json

I get my data in a json format after I execute an sql query(MYSQL) to the server and I would like somehow to group the data regarding the fields with common name.This is the code I handle the data and my result after the execution of the query.

```
<?php

$serverName = "localhost";
$userName = "root";
$password = "root";
$database = "eshop";

// Create connection with the database
$conn = new mysqli($serverName, $userName, $password , $database);

//Retrieves the two values sent from the ajax request
$userName = $_GET["userName"];

// Check the status of the connection
if ($conn->connect_error)
{
    alert("The connection has timed-out!!!");
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);

}

else
{
    $data = new stdclass();
    $data->status = "";
    $past_orders = [];

    $previous_orders_sql =  mysqli_query($conn , 
     "SELECT order_products.order_id , order_date , product_id , price
      FROM   register , orders , order_products , products
      WHERE  register.user_id = orders.user_id
      AND    orders.order_id  = order_products.order_id
      AND    products.product_id = order_products.product_num
      AND    user_name = '$userName'");


    if(mysqli_num_rows($previous_orders_sql)>0)
    {

        $data->status = "OK";

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $previous_orders_sql , MYSQLI_ASSOC))
        {
            $data-> past_orders[] = $row;
        }

    }

    else
    {
        $data->status = "Failed";
        mysqli_error($conn);
    }

}

echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

**The results that I get:**

```
{"past_orders":
[{"order_id":"1","order_date":"2012-12-27","product_id":"1","price":"12.40"},{"order_id":"1","order_date":"2012-12-27","product_id":"2","price":"32.00"},{"order_id":"1","order_date":"2012-12-27","product_id":"3","price":"25.00"},{"order_id":"3","order_date":"2016-01-12","product_id":"1","price":"12.40"},{"order_id":"3","order_date":"2016-01-12","product_id":"6","price":"28.00"},{"order_id":"3","order_date":"2016-01-12","product_id":"7","price":"37.00"},{"order_id":"4","order_date":"2014-04-06","product_id":"1","price":"12.40"},{"order_id":"4","order_date":"2014-04-06","product_id":"2","price":"32.00"},{"order_id":"4","order_date":"2014-04-06","product_id":"5","price":"13.50"}]}
```

**So I would like to have something that will group the data regarding the order_id (as order_id and order_date are the same for some of the results) and have something like:**

```
{"past_orders":

[{"order_id":"1","order_date":"2012-12-27", "products":["product_id":"1","price":"12.40"},"product_id":"2","price":"32.00"},"product_id":"3","price":"25.00"}],

{"order_id":"3","order_date":"2016-01-12","products":["product_id":"1","price":"12.40"},{"product_id":"6","price":"28.00"},{"product_id":"7","price":"37.00"}],

{"order_id":"4","order_date":"2014-04-06","products":["product_id":"1","price":"12.40"},{"product_id":"2","price":"32.00"},{"product_id":"5","price":"13.50"}]}
```

If any extra code required for the answers please let me know to post it.

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and yes, you'll need extra code. if you want a more complicated structure than the simple "flat" array that the fetch() call returns, then you'll have to provide the code to build that structure.

Comment: I think Marc is indirectly trying to say use POST not GET when using results in SQL statements.

Comment: Do you mean the code(the queries) that I have used to create the tables or something else? Actually I have some problems when I use POST and this is the reason I use the GET method in this case.Probably the local server I am working on at the moment needs some configuration that I haven't found yet in order to accept POST requests.

Comment: $userName = $_GET["userName"];  

When you pass the username over to this .php file you should use post instead of get. Get creates a URL that can be visibly seen or modified by visitors. A visitor could insert SQL in the url instead of their username and when you use that SQL in your statement at the end user_name = '$userName'" it could really be AND user_name = 'their user) INSERT ANY SQL QUERY YOU WANT'

Comment: Also, switching to POST really is just a deterrent. If you want to be 1000% safe, you should sanitize everything you put in your queries

Comment: Thanks guys for the advice.As I said earlier I tried to use POST in order to pass the data, but everytime without any particular reason I was receiving and undefined index error on the server side.Then when I just return to the use of GET method(without any other changes at all just replacing the word POST with GET) the error dissapeared.For that reason I carried on with GET. I presume becuae I couldn't manage to find out yet that the error is related to the configuration of the local MySQL sever I use at the momemt.

Answer (score 2):

I would redo your `while` iteration in this manner:

```
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($previous_orders_sql, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

        if (!isset($data->past_orders[$row['order_id']])) {
            $order_arr = array(
                "order_id" => $row['order_id'],
                "order_date" => $row['order_date']
            );
            $data->past_orders[$row['order_id']] = $order_arr;
        }

        $data->past_orders[$order['order_id']]['products'][] = array(
            "product_id" => $row['product_id'],
            "price" => $row['price']
        );
    }
```

That way your results are in a nice set as such:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'order_id' => int 1
      'order_date' => string '2012-12-27' (length=10)
      'products' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => 
            array (size=2)
              'product_id' => int 1
              'price' => float 12.4
          1 => 
            array (size=2)
              'product_id' => int 2
              'price' => float 32
          2 => 
            array (size=2)
              'product_id' => int 3
              'price' => float 25
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'order_id' => int 3
      'order_date' => string '2016-01-12' (length=10)
      'products' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => 
            array (size=2)
              'product_id' => int 1
              'price' => float 12.4
          1 => 
            array (size=2)
              'product_id' => int 6
              'price' => float 28
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      'order_id' => int 4
      'order_date' => string '2014-04-06' (length=10)
      'products' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => 
            array (size=2)
              'product_id' => int 1
              'price' => float 12.4
          1 => 
            array (size=2)
              'product_id' => int 2
              'price' => float 32
          2 => 
            array (size=2)
              'product_id' => int 5
              'price' => float 13.5
```

Also, your SQL query is not efficient. You should use `JOINs` instead:

```
SELECT o.order_id, o.order_date, p.product_id, p.price
FROM orders as o 
JOIN register as r ON r.user_id=o.user_id
JOIN order_products as op ON op.order_id=o.order_id
JOIN products as p ON p.product_id=op.product_num
WHERE r.username = '$userName'
```

Comment: That works exactly the way I wanted to.I haven't changed the query in order to get the results as I needed but as I understood it is only matter of efficiency.I am not used to JOINs yet so that's why I haven' implemented them to the query.Thank you very much for your answer as It was very helpful.

Comment: no problem, im glad i was able to help. Please accept my answer by checking off the checkmark next to this answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to re-structure this data structure so that it's easier to work with it. The simple version could be this:

```
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $previous_orders_sql , MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
        if(!isset($data->past_orders[$row['order_id']]))
          $data->past_orders[$row['order_id']] = array();
        }

        $data->past_orders[$row['order_id']][] = $row;
    }
```

You can further massage this array to get exactly what you need, if that's really necessary.

Comment: The answer was half the way through as the data weren't inserted in the table however the answer could give a good and helpful  guide in order to proceed on your own and get the desired results.As you mentioned you can handle the arrays in that way to get exactly what you need.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Put another line in the query that orders by ID and then in the where statement put an internal where. Like this:

```
 $previous_orders_sql =  mysqli_query($conn , 
 "SELECT order_products.order_id , order_date , product_id , price
  FROM   register , orders , order_products , products
  WHERE  register.user_id = orders.user_id
  AND    orders.order_id  = order_products.order_id
  AND    products.product_id = order_products.product_num
  AND    user_name = '$userName'
  order by orders.order_id desc");


if(mysqli_num_rows($previous_orders_sql)>0)
{

    $data->status = "OK";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $previous_orders_sql , MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
        $idvar = $row[order_id];

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $previous_orders_sql , MYSQLI_ASSOC))
            {
             if ($row[order_id] == $idvar)
             $data-> past_orders[] = $row[order_date].$row[product_id].$row[price] etc etc etc;
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: If you change the query it doesn't make any difference.Actually you miss the results and you get only one product every time.So the solution was hidden in the manipulation of the data on the php side by handling the arrays and placed the data accordingly.Thanks for the answer and your time.